# Connecting to Microsoft SQL Server on ODBC using R in Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-16.04, freetds, rodbc, unixodbc

I was able to get it completely working on Windows 7, but I have to move it to a Linux server. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 64-bit in a VM right now for testing before I replicate the process on the server.

I'm pretty sure the issue is somewhere in my FreeTDS or DSN setup.

**Should I stop wasting my time and just use Python? Or will I have this same issue with ODBC and unixODBC?**

**Full R script:**

```
library(RODBC)

#saving from a .csv to dataframe df
df <- read.csv("./Documents/test.csv")

#creating connection to db
conn <- odbcDriverConnect('myDSN')

#writing
sqlSave(conn, df, tablename = 'dbo.test0', append = F, rownames = F, verbose = TRUE, safer = true, fast = F)
```

**R Console**

```
> conn <- odbcDriverConnect('myDSN')
```

Returns error message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("myDSN") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect("myDSN") : ODBC connection failed
```

Here's my ODBC and FreeTDS config:

**/etc/odbc.ini**

```
[myDSN]
APP = unixodbc
Description     = master on DBNAME
Driver          = TDSdriver
Server          = SERVNAME
Database        = DBNAME
Port            = 1433
Username = UNAME
Password = PW
#Trace           = No
#TraceFile       = /var/log/freetds/freetds--odbc.log
```

**/etc/odbcinst.ini**

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = v0.91 with protocol v7.2
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so


[myDSN0]
APP = unixodbc
Description     = user on DBNAME
Driver          = TDSdriver
Server          = SERVNAME
Database        = DBNAME
Port            = 1433
Username = UNAME
Password = PW
#Trace           = No
#TraceFile       = /var/log/freetds/freetds--odbc.log
```

**/freetds/freetds.conf**

```
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
;   tds version = 4.2

    # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
    # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;   dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;   debug flags = 0xffff

    # Command and connection timeouts
;   timeout = 10
;   connect timeout = 10

        # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
        # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.  
        # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit 
        text size = 64512

[DSN0]
        host = IPADDRESS 
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.2
        client charset = UTF-8
```

Comment: I don't think this is R specific. It's been awhile since I've connected to SQL Server from Linux, but remember having a hard time with Python as well.

Comment: Why don't you use [Microsoft's ODBC Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451(v=sql.110).aspx) driver for SQL Server? Also note that your ini files use a *lot* of different names - `myDSN`, `myDSN0` and `DSN0`

Answer (score 1):

I have RODBC -> FreeTDS -> SQL Server working on linux Mint. It's been a while since I've configured it, but here are some (untested) suggestions:

There are some good install notes at:
http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/09/notes-sqlalchemy-w-pyodbc-freetds-ubuntu/

and of course RTFM:
http://www.freetds.org/userguide/

Can you narrow down the problem by using `isql mydsn` or `tsql -S mydsn` from the command line? Pretty sure this will tell you that your problem is in the FreeTDS setup.

It looks like your odbcinst.ini has a few diffs from mine:

```
[TDSDriver]
Description = TDS driver
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
```

My freetds.conf is the same except `tds version = 8.0` and the name of my server entry is the same as it's entry in odbc.ini.

This and the docs should hopefully get you there.

Comment: You don't need to go through FreeTDS when a [provider-supplied ODBC driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451(v=sql.110).aspx) is available.

Comment: Has anyone tested FreeTDS against MS ODBC for Linux? I'd be interested to see which is faster.